# Clear laravel telescope manually

Tags: php, laravel, telescope

I have a running Laravel application in production, I noticed that the database is getting Giantic so I checked the storage size of each table:
[image]

So it seems the telescope log is consuming a lot maybe because of a broken cron job, any way I run the following command:
`php artisan telescope:prune`
it took ages then it reported that a number of entries are cleaned, but the database size did not change and still the same as the image above
Can I truncate the two telescope tables in the database manually? is it safe?

Comment: The command is `php artisan telescope:clear` to  "Clear all entries from Telescope".  you can list all commands with `php artisan list`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `php artisan telescope:clear` to remove / clear entries from Telescope.

also you might be able to use `php artisan telescope:prune` (have not used it before)

Good luck